# Мобильный мессенджер, что взять за основу?

Tags: мобильные-приложения

Добрый день,
Есть задача написать мобильное приложение аля Viber, WhatsApp. По функционалу нужен обычный текстовый мессенджер, аудио связь и видео чат для iOS, Android, Windows Phone. Посдкажите какие-то готовые решения с открытым кодом либо библиотеки которые можно взять за основу.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете поступить также, как это сделал whatsApp - они взяли обычный jabber (xmpp). Готовых серверов - валом, клиентов, библиотек - валом. Документации - валом. Достаточно расширяемый протокол. Потом приписали своих команд и готово.

Comment: @KoVadim - можно поподробнее? А то я тут как то тоже интересовался темой, а все глухо как в танке. Особливо что касается Push'а и нормальных серверов (пусть даже и коммерческих)

Comment: А что с пушем не так? (кстати, не у всех мессенджеров есть полноценный push). Некоторые стартуют сервис и висят подключенными, тем самым симулируют пуш.

Comment: @KoVadim ссылки в студию серверов с открытым API и с реализацией пуша (можно и без реализации пуша)

Comment: Практически все сервера jabber являются серверами с открытым API (протокол xmpp). Например, [ejabber](http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/) (erlang), [openFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) (java). Более того, они с сорцами - пили-не хочу. А вот пуш придется пилить.